# Как убрать пробелы из строки на PHP?

Tags: php

Как из строки убрать пробелы, например из:

> 16 : 15

сделать

> 16:15

Comment: А как вы сами пробовали это сделать?

Comment: Да ладно вам, тут человек хотя бы не просит `распарсить сайт` или `отправить email с вложением` и т.д.

Comment: Помоему все проще. Автор наверняка когда выводит делает : `<?php echo $h; ?> : <$php echo $m; ?>` а надо : `<?php echo $h; ?>:<$php echo $m; ?>` / `<?php printf("%s:%s", $h, $m); ?>` ...

Comment: Может быть `trim()`?

Answer (score 12):

так `str_replace(' ', '', '16 : 15');`

Answer (score 5):

```
$text = "16 : 15";
$result = preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $text);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Из пушки по воробьям... Не нужны здесь регулярки.

Comment: @AK ага лихо, автор не удержался от downvote

Comment: @AK, всегда надо держать в голове не только автора вопроса но и тех, кто может позже прийти по ссылке. И если для автора это из пушки по воробьям, то другому пожет понадобиться убирать любые пробельные символы, а не только пробелы

Comment: @Ипатьев Тогда видимо на другой вопрос попадут, более подходящий - но даже если и так, то хорошо бы парой фраз описать своё решение.

Answer (score 5):

Чего уж там..

```
$text = '16 : 15';

$chars = preg_split('//u', $text, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$resultChars = array_filter($chars, function($char){
    return !preg_match('/ /u', $char);
});
$result = implode('', $resultChars);

var_dump($result); // string(5) "16:15"
```

*Из серии "Вредные советы"*

Comment: :D upvote за чувство юмора